# postgreSQL fatal error windows

Tags: postgresql, psql

recently i have installed postgresql 9.4 on my windows 8 machine
while installing PostgreSQL though GUI interface it prompt me for password 
i entered password and then installed process completed afterward.
when i go cmd prompt (through administrative right)and type "psql" it prompts me for password ,when i enter the same password i used while installing PostgreSQL i get following error.

```
C:\Users\saphal>psql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "saphal"
```

please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
psql postgres <user_name>
```

Where `postgres` is the name of the main database and `<user_name>` is the user that owns the postgres installation. Usually this will be `postgres` or `psql` too, but it they don't work, try your own user name. (I'm not sure this is set up on a Windows system.)

Comment: Default user is postgres on windows, like in Linux.

Comment: Still i am getting this error message 

C:\Users\saphal>psql postgres saphal

Password for user saphal:

psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "saphal"

Comment: What happens if you try `psql postgres postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the installation created a default role called "postgres". Try running the psql command with the username option:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then when asked for the password use the one you specified during the installation.